# how to check if a exact dictionary is in an array? javascript

Tags: javascript

Basically I want this to output true:

```
const array = [{"a": "b"}]
const x = {"a": "b"}

console.log(array.includes(x)) // output is false
```

I tried to google but I could only find a solution if it was not in array like comparing two dictionaries

For example

```
// JSON.stringify({"a", "b"}) === JSON.stringify(x) 


for(let val of array) {
    if(JSON.stringify(val) === JSON.stringify(x)) {
        console.log("found")
    }
}
```

Which I could do if I iterate through the entire array to check, but wondering if there is a simpler way.